# How to detect Pull to Show More event in Lightning Components

Tags: javascript, salesforce1-app, lightning-aura-components

Is there a way we can detect Pull to Show More event and load the data accordingly?My objective is that, user will be displayed first 50 items that he is searching for and upon sliding the screen up he should be able to see next 50 items of search results.

Comment: So are you trying to implement a kind of infinite scrolling feature in your UI?

Comment: Actually, I am making a callout for pulling the data from external system to display it in Salesforce. Instead of pulling all of the data at once. I would like to pull page by page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my exploration of the one.app code in debug mode, your component needs to implement `ui:handlesShowMore`, but we don't seem to be able to implement it yet. This looks like another feature that isn't there yet.